# Using Service Account with google cloud dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a Dataflow job with the service account.
I am using the GcpOptions flags:

```
--serviceAccountKeyfile="dataflow-service-account.p12" --serviceAccountName="dataflow"
```

I am getting following error:

```
Unable to verify that GCS bucket exists.com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DataflowPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(DataflowPathValidator.java:84)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DataflowPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(DataflowPathValidator.java:63)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:274)
```

I would like to use service account credentials against application default credentials.

Comment: This is most often a problem with either (1) the path not existing or (2) the specified service accounts not actually have permissions to the given paths.

Comment: It works if i give following value to serviceAccountName flag:
--serviceAccountName="dataflow@my-project.gserviceaccount.com"

Documentation is misleading, we are actually giving "Service account ID" value to serviceAccountName flag and not "Service account name".

Answer (score 4):

I am posting an update on this question because the parameter name changed.

The parameter is now `--serviceAccount` in **Java**, and `--service_account_email` in **Python**.

The specified SA should have the following form: `my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Setting this value will change the **worker service account**, complete explanations could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specifying_a_user-managed_worker_service_account).

Answer (score 2):

*serviceAccountName* may be the full email address of the service account. That's usually how they are identified in google APIs.  Usually something like: *name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com*

Also, you will need to add a whack of roles in IAM as per [the docs.](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/access-control#creating_jobs)

I needed:

1. Compute Instance Admin
2. Dataflow Developer
3. Dataflow Worker
4. Logs Writer
5. Service Account Actor
6. Storage Object Admin