# How to run GCP Dataflow as a Service Account

Tags: python, dataflow, google-cloud-platform

Right now when I kick off the dataflow it kicks it off as my UserName. Is there a way to run the GCP Dataflow as a service account? If so, can you provide any samples?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535285/using-service-account-with-google-cloud-dataflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Service Account with google cloud dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535285/using-service-account-with-google-cloud-dataflow)

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To set up service account based authentication:

In the GCP Console, go to the Create service account key page.
[Here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey)

From the Service account list, select New service account.
In the Service account name field, enter a name.
From the Role list, select Project > Owner.

Note: The Role field authorizes your service account to access resources. You can view and change this field later by using the GCP Console. If you are developing a production app, specify more granular permissions than Project > Owner. For more information, see granting roles to service accounts.

Click Create.

A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer.

Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again.

You can get more information from here : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python